# Return Object in Array based on matched data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, match

I have a json array of about 30 objects. Here's a sample object from the array:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Valle",
    "activities": "night-life",
    "food": "fancy-food",
    "sport" : "baseball",
    "geoProfile": "artsy",
    "priority": 2
}
```

I am building out another object on a page based on user input.  The user will choose between radio buttons and after they have made their choices, I will have an object such as:

```
{geoProfile: "artsy", activities: "nature", food: "fancy-food", sport: "cricket"}
```

I am using jQuery's `$.each()` method to go through each object as follows:

```
$.each(self.data(), function (i, s) {
    if (s.geoProfile == self.prefLocation() &&
        s.activities == self.prefActivity() &&
        s.food == self.prefFood() &&
        s.sport == self.prefSport()) {
        optionMatched = s;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will return an object that has all four matches, but how can I return the json object that has the most matches to the user-built object? If two match, I want to then look at the "priority" property and return the one with the lowest priority.

Comment: For starters, you'll need to iterate through your array and compare their values to what the user entered. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MikeC see edits above, thanks for responding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and build a new array with the sum of the matched properties.

Later you can [sort with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and use the result for sorting and get the first element.

```
var data = [/* your data here */],
    search = { geoProfile: "artsy", activities: "nature", food: "fancy-food", sport: "cricket" },
    result = data.map(function (a, i) {
        return {
            count: Object.keys(search).reduce(function (r, k) { return r + +(a[k] === search[k]); }, 0),
            priority: a.priority,
            index: i
        }
    });

result.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count || a.priority - b.priority;
});
```

A single loop solution

```
var data = [/* your data here */],
    search = { geoProfile: "artsy", activities: "nature", food: "fancy-food", sport: "cricket" },
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(r, 0, 4) + '</pre><hr>');
        var o = {
            count: Object.keys(search).reduce(function (q, k) { return q + +(a[k] === search[k]); }, 0),
            priority: a.priority,
            index: i
        };
        if (!i || o.count > r[0].count || o.count === r[0].count && o.priority < r[0].priority) {
            return [o];
        }
        o.count === r[0].count && o.priority === r[0].priority && r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I understand.  So in your example, 'data' would be my json objects and 'search' would be the object that gets built by the user?

Comment: right. the data keeps the array with the objects you have and search is the wanted part to look for.

Comment: Does this take the priority value into account?

Comment: @MikeC, i do not understand this part.

Comment: "If two match, I want to then look at the "priority" property and return the one with the lowest priority"

Comment: actually the `result` contains all sums (for each element of data). it could be used for returning a total result.

Comment: Right, I know what you're doing. But if two objects have equal sums, OP wants to select the one with a lower `priority` value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117462/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-mike-c).

Comment: Perfect Nina, all the OP needs to do now is wrap into a function and call it a day.

Comment: @MikeC , why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when I hit the count.Object line?

Comment: @JordanBarber Do you have an object named `search`? It appears that `search` is `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just track the number of matches and update your selected one based on if it has more matches.

```
var numOfMatches = 0;
$.each(self.data(), function(i, s) {
  var matchingProperties = 0;
  if (s.geoProfile == self.prefLocation()) {
    matchingProperties++;
  }
  if (s.activities == self.prefActivity()) {
    matchingProperties++;
  }
  if (s.food == self.prefFood()) {
    matchingProperties++;
  }
  if (s.sport == self.prefSport()) {
    matchingProperties++;
  }

  if (matchingProperties === 0 || matchingProperties < numOfMatches) {
    return;
  }

  if (!optionMatched // Grab the first match
      || matchingProperties > numOfMatches // or if more properties match
      || s.priority < optionMatched.priority) { // or the one with a lower priority
    optionMatched = s;
    numOfMatches = matchingProperties;
  }
});
```

Or you could simplify the initial counting using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var numOfMatches = 0;
$.each(self.data(), function(i, s) {
  var matchingProperties = [
    s.geoProfile == self.prefLocation(),
    s.activities == self.prefActivity(),
    s.food == self.prefFood(),
    s.sport == self.prefSport()
  ].filter(function(val) { return val; }).length;

  if (matchingProperties === 0 || matchingProperties < numOfMatches) {
    return;
  }

  if (!optionMatched // Grab the first match
      || matchingProperties > numOfMatches // or if more properties match
      || s.priority < optionMatched.priority) { // or the one with a lower priority
    optionMatched = s;
    numOfMatches = matchingProperties;
  }
});
```